# Converting strings to std::__ndk1 instead of std::__1 which compiling POCO with NDK r20b

Tags: c++11, cmake, android-ndk, poco, poco-libraries

I'm compiling poco for android with NDK-r20b where the strings are converting to `std::__ndk1` intead of `std::__1`. My android build aws server requires it to be built with `std::__1`. Is there any way if I can build it with `std::__1`.

**Current Build is:**

```
0000000000000000 DF UND 0000000000000000 Poco::URI::URI(Poco::URI const&)
0000000000000000 DF UND 0000000000000000 Poco::URI::URI()
0000000000000000 DF UND 0000000000000000 Poco::URI::URI(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator > const&)
```

**Expected Build:**

```
0000000000000000 DF UND 0000000000000000 Poco::URI::URI(Poco::URI const&)
0000000000000000 DF UND 0000000000000000 Poco::URI::URI()
0000000000000000 DF UND 0000000000000000 Poco::URI::URI(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&)
```

Can anyone please help if how can I achieve it?

Comment: Is this a problem with Android?  See this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/o-zDdrq09yk.  Not a problem with Poco.

Comment: "My android build aws server requires it to be built with std::__1" `__1` instead of `__ndk1` means it's not built for the NDK and is not compatible with apps. How is AWS requiring this?